# Testing vue component with Jest doesn't seem to use my mocked store getters

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

My component's template contains the following element:

```
<v-text-field v-model="user.first_name" />
```

In my vuex store I declare a state

```
state: {
  user: { first_name: '' }
}
```

and a getter

```
getUserInfo(state) {
  return state.user;
}
```

My component on `created()` does the following:

```
this.user = { ...this.$store.getters.getUserInfo };
```

this.user is declared like so:

```
private user!: User;
```

In the test for this component I use beforeEach to mock the store:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    vuetify = new Vuetify();
    getters = {
        getUserInfo: () => ({ first_name: 'Test' })
    }
    store = new Vuex.Store({
        getters,
        state: {
            user: { first_name: 'Test' }
        }
    });
});
```

This should call the mocked getter on component created() and set the input value to 'Test' via the v-model.

```
console.log(wrapper.find('v-text-field-stub').text());
```

Returns an empty string. I'm reading there are lots of problems with vue-testing-utils and vuetify. (indeed I couldn't find a way to select the raw input element corresponding to the text-field)

To debug further, I tried displaying `wrapper.vm.$data`

```
class_property_1: [Getter/Setter],
class_property_2: [Getter/Setter],
```

but nothing about my `user`.

The test:

```
it('shows input with text', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
        mocks: {
            $store: store
        },
        localVue,
        vuetify
    });
    console.log(wrapper.vm.$data);
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.user.first_name).toBeTruthy(); // user is undefined
});
```

Do I need to explicitly call the getter in my test although it's called inside created()?

I tried making the getter getUserInfo() return a different string than 'Test' but

```
console.log(store.state.user.first_name);
```

still returns 'Test'

**EDIT:**

Using mount instead of shallowMount solves the text-field problem.

However `console.log(wrapper.find('input').text());` is still empty

Comment: Replace `mocks: { $store: store },...` with simply `store,...`. It's already mocked and it shouldn't be bound to `$store`, but to `store`, just like in `main.(js|ts)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you may have some problems with your getter. Try something more like this:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    const vuetify = new Vuetify();
    const getters = {
        getUserInfo: (state) => state.user.first_name
    }
     const store = new Vuex.Store({
        getters,
        state: {
            user: { first_name: 'Test' }
        }
    });
});
```

Basicly it looks like your code for getters isn't getting a value, but instead trying to set it. Also, you aren't declaring your vars for vuetify or getters correctly inside that enclosure. JS is loosely type, so it might let you get away with it, but you might get some results you don't expect or at the very least not pass a linter.

Comment: My getter actually works. But using mount instead of shallow I could select the raw input and use '.element' instead of '.text()' to see my value change. I'm using your version of the getter though. It's better.